# How to change the wind speed after a farm is instantiated?

Tags: floris

When I set the wind speed parameter, it doesn't look like the FLORIS flow field is reconstructed.

```
In [1]: %run example_optimization.py
8297477.650646916

In [2]: oldfield = floris.farm.flow_field.u_field

In [3]: floris.farm.wind_speed
Out[3]: 10.0

In [4]: floris.farm.wind_speed = 20

In [5]: newfield = floris.farm.flow_field.u_field

In [6]: np.sum(oldfield - newfield)
Out[6]: 0.0
```

How to I tell FLORIS to recompute the wind field after I reset the wind speed? I expected the difference between the old flow field and new flow field to be nonzero.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This answer is out of date given the new version of FLORIS, change of wind speed is now set by calling reinitailize flow field.  From example 0005:

```
# Initialize FLORIS model
fi = wfct.floris_utilities.FlorisInterface("example_input.json")

# Change wind speed to 8 m/s
fi.reinitialize_flow_field(wind_speed=8.0)
```

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a misunderstanding in how python defines variables. Specifically, variables in python are actually pointers to memory. In your case, `oldfield` and `newfield` are pointing to the same memory address. So when you change wind_speed, you're doing it to both variables since they're actually the same thing.

I bet `newfield is oldfield` returns `True`?

Try a `copy.deepcopy` of the flow field or floris object before modifying any parameters.

FYI Here's a really nice explanation of python variables: http://scottlobdell.me/2013/08/understanding-python-variables-as-pointers/